# Facebook Deauthorization ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have been through all of the posts about the Facebook deauthorization url and none of them address my issue.  I an have ASP.Net Web Api 2 endpoint, but I cannot get the ping to come through correctly.  Here is what my Route signature looks like:

```
[AllowAnonymous, Route("FacebookDeauthorize"), HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FacebookDeauthorize(string signed_request)
{
    //code for reading it
}
```

This results in a 404, so I tried changing the type to object and getting the type so i could figure out what it was coming through as.  It threw a null reference exception when i tried access the object, so I think its just not coming through at all.  Since this is Web API, I can't look to the request for a form to get the signed request from.  Has anyone successfully gotten this to work with Web Api?  Any help/pointers as to what the route signature should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who finds this, here is the working endpoint for asp.net web api and the Facebook c# sdk, trick is to use a model and not a primitive:

```
public class FacebookDeauthModel
{
    public string signed_request { get; set; }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("FacebookDeauthorize")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FacebookDeauthorize(FacebookDeauthModel model)
{
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
    dynamic signedRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fb.ParseSignedRequest("YOUR_APP_SECRET", model.signed_request).ToString());

    string FBUserID = signedRequest.user_id;

    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindBy(x => x.FBAppID == FBUserID);
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.IsActive = false;
        user.InactiveReason = "Facebook deauthorized on " + DateTime.UtcNow;
        await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }
    else
    {
        _tracer.Error(Request, "FacebookDeauthorize", "Facebook tried to deauthorize a user we do not have record of, FBAppID: {0}", FBUserID);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```